# Android Floating buttons are not set at a fixed position

Tags: android, android-layout

I am showing the 2 floating buttons in my activity but the floating buttons are setting at bottom end when there is no data to show in the activity. if records are show in the activity then the floating buttons are showing after the records instead of at a fix position

Following is my activity layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/login_background"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@color/login_header"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgInfo"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:src="@drawable/info" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgLogout"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="290dp"
                android:src="@drawable/logout" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/logo1" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingStart="120dp">

            <ImageView

                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:background="@color/login_header"
                android:src="@drawable/userprofile" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:fontFamily="@font/segoeui"
                android:paddingStart="20dp"
                android:text="@string/name"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/machineLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scrollbars="vertical">

        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/search"
    android:layout_width="46dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/search" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/addNew"
    android:layout_width="46dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/add" />
```

Following the screen shot
[image]

Comment: You should have to put Floating button in master parent layout(Relativelayout). You have putted it to sub layout(LinearLayout) which also contains recyclerview. So, if recyclerview add items then button will move down.

Comment: I had the same problem, when fabs not fixed in their places, so I used CircleImageView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imgInfo"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_message" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imgLogout"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="290dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_message" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/kid_goku" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:paddingStart="120dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:src="@drawable/kid_goku" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:paddingStart="20dp"
                    android:text="name"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/machineLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scrollbars="vertical">

            </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>


        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:layout_width="46dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/addNew"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_message" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/addNew"
        android:layout_width="46dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_message" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: i have updated my question can you please tell me where  i am doing wrong

Comment: @pravinmaske just copy paste my answer in your layout

Comment: @pravinmaske remove `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` from your search FAB and add this `android:layout_above="@+id/addNew" it will work

Comment: Thank you @Nilesh Rathod

Answer (score 0):

Use **CoordinatorLayout** as root view.
And Also add **app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end(specify as you need)**" in FloatingActionButton